Given an array of numbers(arr) and the length of the array(n) as arguments, how do you create a tribonacci sequence?
Consider:
function tribonacci(arr, n){
    let sum = 0;
    for(let i= arr.length-1; i > arr.length-4; i--){
       sum += arr[i]     
    }

    while(arr.length < n){
      arr.push(sum);
    }
  
    return arr; 
}

console.log(tribonacci([1, 1, 1], 10));

With ([1, 1, 1], 10), it should log [1, 1, 1, 3, 5, 9, 17, 31, 57, 105] since it's following a tribonacci sequence, and we want it to stop executing once we have 10 integers.
Initially, the for loop executed fine, so if I gave it [1,1,1] it would log [1,1,1,3], and if I gave it [1,1,1,3] it would print [1,1,1,3,5] and so on. Then I added the while loop to specify the length(n) at which I wanted the array to end. Now the output keeps logging 3 over and over until there's 10 integers: [1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3].
I understood that it's repeatedly pushing the next number in the sequence (which is 3), having calculated [1,1,1] instead of recalculating starting from the last index in the array... So I tried a bunch of different things like nesting the for loop inside the while loop or attempting a do...while loop, etc. to no avail. Do I need to keep resetting the calculation in the while loop? What am I doing wrong and how do I fix this?

If you keep on pushing arr.push(sum)in a loop, without modifying sum within that loop as well, then of course you will keep getting the same number. Just putting everything expect the return statement into the loop should do the trick - https://jsfiddle.net/vojryc9q/

@CBroe In my attempts at debugging I actually did think of that, so I too nested everything (apart from the return statement) into the while loop EXCEPT for the let sum = 0; variable, which gave me an output of:  [1,1,1, 3, 8, 20, 51,130, 331, 843]. I just don't understand how moving the sum = 0 var into the loop changes everything because I just left it thinking it's a global variable, so technically the loop would be able to change the sum even if its not in the loop? Obvs I was wrong but I really don't get it. Could you possibly explain why I got that output?

"so technically the loop would be able to change the sum even if its not in the loop" - of course it is able to do that either way, but it simply makes a difference where you set it to 0 (again.) If you only do that once before the loop, then of course the values across all loop iterations will keep adding up.

Your code executes each loop only once, so you calculate the sum of the three first elements in the array once and then proceed to append this sum to the array until its lenght reaches n.
Instead you want to calculate the sum n - 3 times by putting your loops together:
function tribonacci(arr, n){
    // It's a good idea to add validation for the array's length to avoid errors 
    if(arr.length < 3){
        return arr;
    }
    while(arr.length < n){
        let sum = 0;
        for(let i= arr.length-1; i > arr.length-4; i--){
            sum += arr[i]     
        }
        arr.push(sum);
    }
  
    return arr; 
}

console.log(tribonacci([1, 1, 1], 10));


You need to repeatedly calculate the sum of the last 3 numbers in the array and add that sum to the array until the array length is n.


const tribonacci = (arr, n) => {
    // TODO: Validate arguments (like ensure arr is at least [1,1,1])
    
    while (arr.length < n) {
        arr.push(arr[arr.length - 3] + arr[arr.length - 2] + arr[arr.length - 1]);
    }
    return arr;
};

console.log(tribonacci([1,1,1], 20));




You're not correctly updating the values for the tribonacci sequence in each iteration cycle of the while loop. You can fix your tribonacci function to generate the correct sequence like below.
Refer the below code for reference:


function tribonacci(arr, n) {
  let sum = arr[arr.length - 1] + arr[arr.length - 2] + arr[arr.length - 3];
  while (arr.length < n) {
    arr.push(sum);
    sum = arr[arr.length - 1] + arr[arr.length - 2] + arr[arr.length - 3];
  }
  return arr;
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(tribonacci([1, 1, 1], 10)));



